# React useState update problematic

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, react-state-management, use-state

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I have a difficult problem with useState. I want to remove a item from a array and after that I want to do some checks and a xhr call. Let me give you an example:

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([{ id: 'xxx', email: 'xxx@xxx.com' }, { id: 'yyy', email: 'xxx@xxx.com' }]);

const handleRemoveItem = async (index) => {
    const itemEmail = items[index].email;
    const itemsCopy = [...items];
    itemsCopy.splice(index, 1); <-- Remove one item, one should be left
    setItems(itemsCopy);

    const isUnique = await checkUnique(email);
    if(!isUnique) {
        // do something
    }
}

const checkUnique = async (email) => {
    const hasDuplicates = items.filter(item => item.email === email).length > 1; <-- items has already 2 items, but before one was removed
    if(hasDuplicates) {
        return false;
    }

    // Some XHR calls to check the email already exists

}
```

The problem is, that items in `checkUnique` still contains two items. I cannot use useEffect, because I need the removed item in the xhr call. And I don't want to remember the removed item, because it is hard to understand and redundant. Does anyone have an idea how to fix that problem ? 
I thinked about passing `itemsCopy` down to `checkUnique` as parameter, but is this the way to go ?

Comment: Yes, that'd be the way to go, by passing `itemsCopy` into `checkUnique` and then using that to filter the array and check if it has duplicates.

Comment: Okay, but sometimes I am able to call the method `checkUnique` without the parameter `itemsCopy`. Should the items parameter get a default value ?: `const checkUnique = async (email, arr = items)`

Comment: That could work, but you shouldn't be relying on `items` always being up-to-date and you might be getting strange results. What I'd do is to try to keep this function as "pure" as possible and always pass all required arguments so that it's easier to debug instead of relying on variables outside of `checkUnique`'s scope.

Answer (score 0):

Just use it like this; Should help;

```
const handleRemoveItem = async (index) => {
const itemEmail = items[index].email;

setItems((prevState) => {
  return prevState.splice(index, 1);
});

const isUnique = await checkUnique(itemEmail);
if (!isUnique) {
  // do something
}
};
```

Comment: This doesn't really help with anything.

Comment: What is different in your solution to my current example ?